# launch the application on a connected iOS device receive an error

Tags: gluon

I an receiving the following error when I select launchIOSDevice

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':launchIOSDevice
>
> No provisioning profile found matching signing identity 'iPhone     Developer: sunshakir@yahoo.com (Y6W56GXM29)' and app bundle ID     'com.gluonDemoSingle.DemoSingle'

What is the steps need to be taken in Xcode to resolve the problem

Comment: Have you created a provisioning profile with that name and including your identity in the Developer Apple portal? If that's the case, have you installed it to your machine? You can download it from the portal, and double click on it to install it.

Comment: Are you using free or paid developer ID?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use free apple developer account for testing. You have to follow these steps below:

- If you do not have an Apple ID you can use, you can create a new one [here](https://appleid.apple.com).
- Open Xcode and go to `Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts`
- Add your Apple ID
- Under Manage Certificates, add one for iOS Development.
- Now create a new Xcode project, select a simple template like `Single View App`.
- Make sure you set the exact same bundle identifier as the one on your project.
- Connect your device and run the Xcode project. It will install a provisioning profile for that empty app on your device.
- Quit Xcode and go back to your project, try to deploy it to the iOS device without setting the `iosSignIdentity` and `iosProvisioningProfile`).

You can check more detail from my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950698/how-to-testing-gluon-app-on-ios-simulator-or-real-device)